# couchdb get by value, limit, and order by time

Tags: database, view, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB and I'm trying to get the last 50 most recent entries of a user in an app.
I created a view that pulls out the documents for the entries, and I can use the key parameter to get only the docs of a particular user and the limit query to get only 50 entries.

However, I'd like to order the docs by a "timestamp" field (which stores the new Date().getTime() of when the entry was made) in order to ensure that I only get the most recent entries. Is this possible in CouchDB, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve this (at least in the case that you don't have any future dates in your data) by emitting a more complex key like an array of the form [username,datetime].
Then make a view that pulls the documents with a startkey like, for example, ['johndoe',1331388874195] with descending order, and limit to 50. The date should obviously be the current one. CouchDB's [collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Sorting_by_Dates) will make sure the results are first ordered by user and then by date.

Comment: thank you! that worked beautifully :)
I did not know you can use an array as the key, very useful to know!
once again, thank you!!

Comment: oops, noticed a small bug..you need to also include a endkey of ['johndoe', 0] in order to prevent couchdb from returning posts from usernames which start with 'johndoe' like 'johndoe59'.